# Kotlin overload "-" for type String

Tags: string, kotlin, overloading, minus

I've been trying out Kotlin recently. I now have a task that I'm stuck on.
I need to overload the operator "-" for type String. The new function should create a new String out of an existing string without the letter after "-".

Like This:
"Hello World" - 'l' --> "Heo Word"

This is part of my further training. Unfortunately, it is very poorly explained in the documents and most of my class can't handle it either. The teacher just says, "Find it out for yourself."

Unfortunately, since we've only had 2 lessons, I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: Fortunately, it is very well explained in the documents: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html

Comment: Your teacher probably means to read the official documentation on Kotlin. It’s all explained there.

Comment: This question illustrates why operator overloading isn't a good idea once it strays too far from the operator's original meaning. What does it _mean_ to subtract a character from a string: remove the first instance of that character, or the last one, or all of them, or the first of each group of consecutive instances, or something else?  A normal method lets you make that sort of thing clear in the method name, and can have multiple options based on extra params. But an operator can't do any of those. So IMHO operators should only be used when there's only one thing it could possibly mean.

Answer (score 3):

To overload the `-` operator on a string, we need to create an extension function:

```
operator fun String.minus(other: String): String
```

Then, we need to actually replace the string. The kotlin stdlib already has a function that can do this for us:

```
fun String.replace(oldValue: String, newValue: String,  ignoreCase: Boolean = false): String
```

Putting these two together, we get this function:

```
operator fun String.minus(other: String) = this.replace(other, "")
```

We define an overload of the `-` operator for a String, and then call the `replace` method on the receiver.

Try it out [here](https://pl.kotl.in/4uUMg0ENb):

```
operator fun String.minus(other: String) = this.replace(other, "")

fun main() {
    println("Hello World" - "l") // Heo Word
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: it looks like the question wants to subtract a _character_ from the string, while this instead lets you subtract another string.  (Good answer, though.)